# Functional equation with differentiablity

Tags: functions

Q. $f(x)f(y)+2=f(x)+ f(y)+f(xy)$ and $f(1)=2$ and $f'(1)=2$, then find the signum function  $f(x)$.

Putting $y=1/x$ , we get, $f(x)f(1/x)=f(x)+f(1/x)$ ,
I don't know how to proceed after it.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "the signum function for $f(x)$" mean?

Comment: @lulu  sorry, I meant find sgn f(x)  where sgn means signum function.

Comment: I suggest:  first argue that $f(0)=1$ unless $f(x)$ is constant.  Then, suppose there is some $y$ with $f(y)=0$.  Try to show that this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Should stress:  I am not sure that works, but it seems hard to have such a value $y$.